# How to create radio buttons dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 100 questions written in excel. I am getting all data like question nr., question text, options A,B,C and D. I have successful get the question nr. and text but only one radio button is created when I run my project. I want to generate 4 radio buttons for each question. How? Please help me

**Note: dt is datatable that i have been populalted**

```
**CODE**
private void ShowQuestions(DataTable dt)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        Label[] lblQNo = new Label[dt.Rows.Count];
        Label[] lblQText= new Label[dt.Rows.Count];
        RadioButton[] rbs = new RadioButton[4*dt.Rows.Count];
        for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            lblQText[i] = new Label();
            lblQText[i].Text = "<h3>"+dt.Rows[i]["SrNo"].ToString()+"<h3>"+dt.Rows[i]["QuestionText"].ToString()+"</h3><br>";

            for (j = 3; j < 7; j++)
            {
                rbs[i] = new RadioButton();
                rbs[i].Text = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                rbs[i].GroupName = i.ToString();
                divQuestionText.Controls.Add(rbs[i]);


            }
            divQuestionText.Controls.Add(lblQText[i]);




        }
```

**html**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
       <div class="row" runat="server">              
           <div class="col-sm-12" id="divQuestionText" runat="server">

           </div>

           </div> 


    </div>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W2vy.png)

Comment: use a control collection and instantiate the classes for the controls you want.

Comment: For your innermost loop shouldn't it be `innerDiv[i].InnerHtml +=` instead of `innerDiv[i].InnerHtml =` ? Otherwise it will just overwrite the previous iteration.

Comment: Yes  you are right but how will assign it to the html because all html will be generated fdynamically

Comment: runat server won't work here.

Comment: also consider a `Repeater`.

Comment: @Laslos no, it is creating same questiojn more than once with the same id and text

Comment: Well, you are referencing the `DataSource` columns based on the outer loop, so yes, they will be the same. Only code that will change will be `dt.Rows[j][k]`, which I am guessing sets the id for the `input` element.

Comment: @Laslos i have tried but same result. Kindly see the image i have uploaded at the end of question

Comment: The image doesn't tell me anything, what is wrong with what is being produced? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually I want to generate four radio buttons for each quesiotn with its text (text is getting from excel which is not showing)

Comment: Have you updated your code? Is the code you posted in your question what produced the radio buttons in the image?

Comment: @Laslos Yes that is the code into which i have stucked

Comment: Then your two inner loops effectively do nothing. `innerDiv[i].InnerHtml` is set to the last iteration of each.

Comment: @Laslos  can u please write the sample code for me?

Comment: I feel like you don't understand basic looping concepts, I think you should find some training materials on the subject. My last advice would be to move the `outerDiv.Controls.Add(innerDiv[i]);` inside the inner loop, `for (k = 3; k < 7; k++)`

Comment: @Laslos thanks everything is working fine but last index is not showing properly its options are not in its place. I have changed the code look there.

Comment: It is hard to troubleshoot without knowing what your dataset looks like. Are you meaning to add the `label` with the question text to the `div` AFTER you add all of the `RadioButtons`?